# URL Amigável PHP: Não carrega arquivos da Pasta

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7, url-amigável

Tenho no meu diretório raiz o arquivo index.php e o config.php. Dentro da pasta raiz do meu site tenho a pasta pages com os arquivos home.php, login.php e register.php, porém quando tento acessá-los somente o arquivo home.php carrega normalmente, os demais apresentam erro no carregamento.

Erro:

Objeto não encontrado!
A URL requisitada não foi encontrada neste servidor. O link na página referida parece estar com algum erro ou desatualizado. Por favor informe o autor desta página sobre o erro.

Se você acredita ter encontrado um problema no servidor, por favor entre em contato com o webmaster.

Error 404
192.168.64.2
Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d PHP/7.4.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Segue o código para verificação:

arquivo index.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$url = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home');
if (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home');
if(file_exists('pages/'.$url.'.php')) {
include('pages/'.$url.'.php');
} else {
include('pages/404.php');
}
?>
```

Arquivo config.php

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_PATH','http://192.168.64.2/sistema/');
?>
```

obs: Estou usando xampp

Comment: Você criou um arquivo `.htaccess` para configurar o Apache?

Comment: E está tentando acessar com *query string* ou não? Ex: 1. `localhost/?url=login`  ou  2. `localhost/login`.

Comment: Sim, tenho o arquivo .htacess na pasta raiz. Quando acesso http://192.168.64.2/sistema/ ele carrega o home.php normalmente porém quando tento acessar o login.php ou o register.php ele apresenta esse erro. Sempre fiz assim no windows e funcionou, estou usando no momento o xampp no macbook. não sei se tem que ser feita alguma configuração no arquivo httpd.conf.

Comment: `AllowOverride` no seu arquivo `httpd.conf` está configurado para `All`?  `AllowOverride All`. Se não estiver, troque para `All` e reinicie o apache.

Comment: *Off-topic*: a linha do seu primeiro `if` termina com `;` e, portanto, seu `if` não está servindo para nada. Esse é um dos motivos que me fazem usar sempre `{ }`. Mas é do gosto de cada um ;)

Comment: Já mudei o AllowOverride para All e continua o mesmo erro x).

Comment: O diretório raiz do Apache está configurado para o diretório raiz do seu site? Quero dizer se você acessa assim `192.168.64.2/?url=login` ou assim `192.168.64.2/sistema/?url=login` ou de outro jeito.

Comment: para acessar o projeto na pasta htdocs tenho que usar o link http://192.168.64.2/sistema/, não consigo acessar a pasta raiz direto por http://192.168.64.2/, ele me direciona direto para http://192.168.64.2/dashboard/. To achando estranho pois ele teria que funcionar pelo localhost:8080, mas só funciona pelo ip.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106307/discussion-between-wesley-goncalves-and-marcos-de-barros-azevedo).

Comment: Para novos visitantes aqui vai a *Conclusão do chat*: Possivelmente era uma configuração do Apache. Após a instalação de uma versão anterior do XAMPP, as URLs voltaram a ser carregadas corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Bom para você ter url amigável você deve ter o arquivo .htaccess nele vão ficar as configurações do apache como redirecionamento, permissões de pastas, quando quero utilizar de url amigáveis utilizo essa configuração abaixo

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: o Arquivo .htaccess está na pasta raiz do projeto. segue arquivo: 
```
rewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ˆ(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes

```